# Animate a graphics with derivative function that gathered from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, graphics

I'm defined W[t] and Q[t] like below. This code is an example that shows my problem. My real code is very long and complex that i cant make change in it. I solved my differential equations but sum function that defined by derivatives the same of W[t] and Q[t] can't be used in animation graphics. If i define them without D[,t] function i could use them in animated graphics but i need them in this form. I can Plot W[t] and Q[t] and i can gather this function output in a desired time easily but i can't animate a ball or line with using W[t] and Q[t]. `/.sol//Evaluate`
Works for plot and animated Plot but didn't work for Animated graphics. please help me for use of my function in animated Plot. My real code is very long and i cant make change in body of code.

```
ClearAll[W, Q, x, sol, a]
W[t_] := Max[Piecewise[{{-1, Q[t] <= 0}, {1, Q[t] > 0}}], 0];
Q[t_] := D[x[t], {t, 2}] + x[t];
sol = NDSolve[{Q[t] + x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 2}, {x, x'}, {t,0,2}];
Plot[(Q[t] + W[t]) /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2}]       (*Correctly worked*)
Animate[Plot[(Q[a] + W[a]) /. sol // Evaluate, {a, 0, t}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1.5}}], {t, 0, 2}]         (*Correctly worked*)
(Q[t] + W[t]) /. sol /. t -> 0.7                        (*Correctly worked*)
Animate[Graphics[{{Circle[{t, (Q[t] + W[t]) /. sol // Evaluate},0.1]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1.5}}], {t, 0,2}] (*!! Didn't work*)
```

I tried for move a ball with radius of 0.1 with this Ndsolved functions but my efforts didn't be successful.

Answer (score 2):

```
W[t_] := Max[Piecewise[{{-1, Q[t] <= 0}, {1, Q[t] > 0}}], 0];
Q[t_] := D[x[t], {t, 2}] + x[t];
sol = NDSolve[{Q[t] + x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 2}, {x, x'}, {t, 
    0, 2}];
T = Table[
   Flatten[{t1, Q[t] + W[t] /. sol /. t -> t1}], {t1, 0., 2, .01}];

L = ListAnimate[
  Table[Graphics[{{Red, Circle[T[[i]], 0.1]}, {Green, 
      Rectangle[{-.1, -1.2}, {2.2, -1.1}]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-.1, 2.2}, {-1.2, 1.5}}], {i, 1, Length[T]}]]
```

[image: fig1]